# where is my app? /data appears empty

Tags: android, sd-card

I almost feel embarrased asking this but I really can't find my app on my phone. I read that the app should be installed in /data/data/ folder but my /data folder appears to be empty when viewed in Astro. My app is most definitely installed on the phone, should I transfer it to the SD for it to become visible? I have an unrooted HTC Desire HD on Orange UK. I just need to have a peek at the SQLite database managed by my App.

Comment: My phone is not rooted. Do I really neeed to root my phone just to see the files created by my app? Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I almost feel embarrased asking this but I really can't find my app on my phone.

Look for it in Settings > Applications to see if it is installed. If it is, any activities you declared in the `LAUNCHER` category (action `MAIN`) will appear in the home screen launcher.

> I read that the app should be installed in /data/data/ folder but my /data folder appears to be empty when viewed in Astro.

You do not have permissions to view that directory on an un-rooted phone.

> My app is most definitely installed on the phone, should I transfer it to the SD for it to become visible?

Your app will not be any more "visible".

> I just need to have a peek at the SQLite database managed by my App.

Add a backup/restore feature to your app that copies your SQLite file to/from external storage. Be sure all your `SQLiteDatabase` objects are closed first, though.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I should have been clearer - the app on my phone is visible and operational but I need to monitor the SQLite db managed by it because I am in the process of writing the methods for my app which manage the DB. I thought I'd have direct access, doh!

Comment: @TomaszRykala: You have direct access to the file on the emulator, but not on standard production hardware. Sorry!

Comment: Not your fault ;) I don't have a rooted phone because I never felt like I needed it, now it looks like I have to, rubbish :( thanks.

Comment: @TomaszRykala: You do not need to root your phone. See the last paragraph of my answer.

Comment: Ahh, thanks! I have helped myself with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170031/backup-and-restore-sqllite-database-to-sdcard

Answer (score 7):

Simple answer would be,

- If you need to browse the "Data" directory in actual phone, it should be a **rooted** device.
- You can simply browse "Data" directory in **simulators**, because, Simulator act as a rooted device and it has all the super user access.

Happy coding!!!

**Update**

There is another way by copying database to your SD card from below function,

```
public void exportDatabse(String databaseName) {
    try {
        File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();

        if (sd.canWrite()) {
            String currentDBPath = "//data//"+getPackageName()+"//databases//"+databaseName+"";
            String backupDBPath = "backupname.db";
            File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
            File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);

            if (currentDB.exists()) {
                FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
                FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
                dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                src.close();
                dst.close();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

root is **not** necessary if your application is debuggable (`android:debuggable="true"`) see [How can I see the contents of a sqlite db of my app in a real device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14155495/how-can-i-see-the-contents-of-a-sqlite-db-of-my-app-in-a-real-device/14157699#14157699)