# How to get variables stored using localStorage.setItem in phonegap in java file

Tags: android, cordova, local-storage

I'm using Phonegap 2.4.0 to build my application 
And used localStorage to get and set variables.
I need to access those variables from java files 
Is that possible
How can I do that.

my code in javascript is :

```
localStorage.setItem("language", "en");
```

I want to access that variable from Java files.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make a native plugin that stores values in android shared preferences and call it each time you add/delete objects in the localstorage.

So, in javascript you don't directly call the localstorage functions, but a wrapper which 1) manipulates the localstorage and then 2) calls the plugin to store it in the shared preferences as well.

Of course this involves a double copy of each object, so you'll have to handle this too, but if modifications to the localstorage are always started from javascript this should not be a problem.

[Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10370005/phonegap-get-localstorage-values-from-java-code) to get details.

Comment: Check this link for it.                                               https://github.com/macdonst/AppPreferences           or    http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.in/2012/06/phongap-android-application-preferences.html