# access to phonegap-created table using Java - android

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have created a table in SQLite using phonegap. How can i have access to this table using Java?
Because i have made a background process (as a phonegap plugin) which needs to retrieve data from the already made table.

Answer (score 0):

Your database is located in

On Eclipse :

> **Window>Open Perspective>Other>DDMS**

-- in File Explorer tab

> **data>data>your_package_name>databases>your_DB_fileName**

So at any point of time if database is successfully create and available in it respective location, then you can read it programatically using the path

> **/data/data/your_package_name/databases/your_DB_fileName**

Comment: I am working on a real device, so i can't see anything in File Explorer.
The "your_DB_fileName" has to do with a name I have already defined before?

Comment: you can connect your device with your PC through USB and debug directly/see the DDMS

Comment: in the "data" section I am not able to see anything.

Comment: are you sure the DB is created?

Comment: surely, i can access the content of the database through phonegap.

Comment: What path you used for DB creation?

Comment: After doing a small research I found that by default PhoneGap will not store the DB in data/data/.. folder of Android system. Hence a guy(Coder_sLaY) modified Cordova in such a way that it will create the database in Android's Default location which is (/data/data/package-name/databases/)  Refer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/9718094/28557

Comment: this solutiuon doesn't work for me and this answer you posted doens't seem to be accepted-solved. Thanks anyway.