# How can I see the contents of a sqlite db of my app in a real device?

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to see the contents of my database created in my app in the device I deploied it. I can use sqlite commands in shell and see in emulator but not in a real device.

Can anyone know how to do it in real device?

Answer (score 7):

root is not necessary if the application is flagged a debuggable. You can use the `run-as` adb command.

e.g. to use sqlite :

```
adb shell "run-as com.your.package sqlite3 databases/database_name"
```

or copy and pull the database :

```
adb shell "run-as com.your.package cat databases/database_name > /sdcard/some_name"
adb pull /sdcard/some_name
```

unfortunately it seems that pre-ICS `run-as` has quite a few bugs, e.g. issue [20792](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=20792) or [13965](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=13965)

Comment: thanks all for reply Phillipe thanks for your reply as well the copy and pull worked for me...

Comment: I'm kicking myself that I didn't find this sooner, as I just spent the last couple of hours rooting my phone but good to know!

Comment: Does not work with non rooted phones, I just tried with a cheap quality Micromax

Comment: Is should work with non rooted phones (It's in fact the whole point of this question) but a lot of phones / android versions include a bugged `run-as` (even recently, see for example [issue 58373](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58373))

Answer (score 2):

Actually your **Real Device is not Rooted** so you **don't have a permission to access** `/data/data/<Application>/database/` directory.

Only one solution **copy that file to external Storage** .. And see it in **SQLiteManager** or any other **SQLite** tools.

Comment: To copy what file? I cant see any sqlite database file in my real device?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a rooted device to access sqlite.

Look at this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856210/access-sqlite-database-on-android-device).

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

You can copy your database in to your sdcard where you can see your database

```
   public void backup() {
        try {
            File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File outputFile = new File(sdcard,
                    "YourDatabase.db");

            if (!outputFile.exists()) 
                 outputFile.createNewFile(); 

            File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();
            File inputFile = new File(data,
                    "data/"+getPackageName()+"/databases/"+"YourDatabase.db");
            InputStream input = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                output.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            output.flush();
            output.close();
            input.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new Error("Copying Failed");
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Am getting java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/databases/timeline.db (No such file or directory) then i tried to list the contents of tht directory File file = new File(Environment.getDataDirectory()+"/data/databases"); File[] listOfFiles = file.listFiles(); I get nullpointer which means not able to access that folder....

Answer (score 0):

Try this function as

`copyFile(new File("data/data/<app>/database"),new File("mnt/sdcard/...."))`.

```
public void copyFile(File filesrc, File filedst)
 {
  try
 {
  FileInputStream localFileInputStream = new FileInputStream(filesrc);
  FileOutputStream localFileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(filedst);
  byte[] arrayOfByte = new byte[1024];
  while (true)
  {
    int i = localFileInputStream.read(arrayOfByte);
    if (i == -1)
    {
      localFileOutputStream.close();
      localFileInputStream.close();
      break;
    }
    localFileOutputStream.write(arrayOfByte, 0, i);
  }
}
catch (Exception localException)
{
  Log.d("XXX", "ExceptioncopyFile:" + localException.getMessage(), localException);
}
```

}