# Android database backup restore

Tags: android, database, sms, backup, restore

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Backup and restore SQLite database to sdcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170031/backup-and-restore-sqlite-database-to-sdcard)

I'm writing an application and I need to be able to backup a database to the sdcard and restore it via java. I first tried just copying it to the sdcard that seems to work fine and after browsing the database it seems to be all there and fine. However i can not seem to restore it if i just copy it back and overwrite the existing one i get force closes. I'm looking to backup the sms database and restore it. Thank you for any help with this issue

Comment: Are you sure you havn't made any locks on the database when trying to overwrite it?

Comment: I dunno i haven't touched the database i just did like with bash at first cp the sms database from /data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/smsmms.db to the sd and then i just tried copying it back and the sms app force closes then

Comment: anyone got any solutions to my problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170031/backup-and-restore-sqlite-database-to-sdcard - This can be useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure to set file permissions back so the sms app has permissions to read the file?

Files stored on sdcard all have `---rwxr-x`, so copying your backed up sms database to `/data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/` will keep those permissions from sdcard, also if you are copying it as root, root will be the owner of the file, denying the sms app write privileges i believe

`-rw-rw---- radio    radio      972800 2011-12-05 06:40 mmssms.db`

there's the db on my device, so after you copy your backup back onto device /data/data
do

`chmod 660 mmssms.db`

and change the ownership back to radio

`chown radio.radio mmssms.db`