# Can I save sqlite database on server in android?

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to know is it possible to directly save the sqlite database on the server.

if yes,How can I do this Please Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite databases on android are private to the device. You can not choose their location either. They will always be stored in a directory under `/data/data` on your device. You can, however, copy it between locations as [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170031/backup-and-restore-sqlite-database-to-sdcard).

Also, as SQLite is a "serverless" database, there's now way of using any "remote database".