# Copy and replace (like backup) android database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, backup

I would like to know how I can make a copy of my current sqlite db to a separate folder.
Also, I need to know how I can replace a brand new database by the stored db.

I can't use the Android backup engine because I will also copy some other files and folders.

Any help is appreciatted!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Backup and restore SQLite database to sdcard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170031/backup-and-restore-sqlite-database-to-sdcard)

Answer (score 0):

Popular question. You can find a few different way to copy files on Android devices, and a SQLite database is a simple, self contained file that you copy/replace like most others. This code works dandy: [How do I backup a database file to the SD card on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1995320/1267661).  You can find other methods in the **Related** column as well. -->