# attempt at programmatic sqlite database repair

Tags: android, sqlite

I discovered that it's possible for an app's database to become corrupt when a user pulls the battery out of the phone. This results in :

> I/Database(1217): sqlite returned: error code = 14, msg = cannot open
> file at source line 25467
>
> E/Database(1217):
> sqlite3_open_v2("/data/data/com.myapp/databases/mydata.db", &handle,
> 6, NULL) failed
>
> W/dalvikvm(1217): Exception
> Landroid/database/sqlite/SQLiteException; thrown while initializing
> Lcom/myapp/database/SQLhelper;
>
> D/AndroidRuntime(1217): Shutting down
> VM
>
> W/dalvikvm(1217): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught
> exception (group=0x40015560)

**Premise**

I read that using .dump can recover userful data. So I took the following approach...

**Execution**

```
final String strDBpath = Application.getContext().getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).getAbsolutePath();

final File fDBsrc = new File(strDBpath);
final File fDBtrgt = new File(strDBpath.replace(".db", "new.db"));

final String strExeCmd = "sqlite3 "+fDBsrc+" .dump | sqlite3 "+fDBtrgt;

boolean bSuccess = true;

try
{
    Log.i(TAG, "executing "+strExeCmd);
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(strExeCmd);
    process.waitFor();
} catch (Exception er)
{
    bSuccess = false;
}
```

**Result**
HOWEVER - listing the /data/data/com.myapp/databases did not reveal a new database.

is this a permissions problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the best way to avoid DB corruption is to take periodic snapshots of the database when it's in a known working state. One day, when the DB fails to open you'd restore it using this method... [Backup and restore SQLite database to sdcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170031/backup-and-restore-sqlite-database-to-sdcard)

Answer (score 0):

The sqlite docs (http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html) on .dump state

Use the ".dump" command to convert the entire contents of a database into a single ASCII text file. This file can be converted back into a database by piping it back into sqlite3.

so you need to pipe back to sqlite3 to restore the db

If you need to do this in your app you may be able to do this via an Runtime().getRuntime().exec call

Comment: that's what I tried and the .dump didn't work from within the app. It did work from the terminal