# Android how to make database backup?

Tags: android, database, cloud, database-backups

I want to make database backup to my app, so I'm looking for the best way.

I should save a copy of the database and programatically make the backup?

Can make database backup with backup manager?

Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going just to let the user save current state of the application for some reasons, db file(s) copying will be fine. Your can find plenty of samples here, like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2251647/812046

But if you need to restore your data on another devices, you should think of anything like `sqlite .dump` and you'll have to implement it yourself. As I know if you don't have root you will not be able to use native sqlite dump.
Once I used simple csv files to copy data between android device and openbsd machine. Worked fine for small amounts of data.