# Android copy Sqlite database from app package "\\data\\com.android.pcr\\databases\\vrp_db" to sd card folder backup

Tags: java, android, sqlite, database-backups

is there any way to copy "\data\com.android.pcr\databases\vrp_db" to sd card.
i want to take the backup of my database so that if app is uninstall or sd card is inserted into another phone user can backup database.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite databases are completely self-contained files and are portable — you can just copy the entire file straight to the SD card.

Details : [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170031/backup-and-restore-sqlite-database-to-sdcard/37261271)